# How to Prevent I/O Access in C++ or Native Compiled Code

Tags: c++, networking, io, operating-system, storage

I know this may be impossible but I really hope there's a way to pull it off.  Please tell me if there's any way.

I want to write a sandbox application in C++ and allow other developers to write native plugins that can be loaded right into the application on the fly.  I'd probably want to do this via DLLs on Windows, but I also want to support Linux and hopefully Mac.

My issue is that I want to be able to prevent the plugins from doing I/O access on their own.  I want to require them to use my wrapped routines so that I can ensure none of the plugins write malicious code that starts harming the user's files on disk or doing things undesireable on the network.

My best guess on how to pull off something like this would be to include a compiler with the application and require the source code for the plugins to be distributed and compiled right on the end-user platform.  Then I'd need an code scanner that could search the plugin uncompiled code for signatures that would show up in I/O operations for hard disk or network or other storage media.

My understanding is that the STD libaries like fstream wrap platform-specific functions so I would think that simply scanning all the code that will be compiled for platform-specific functions would let me accomplish the task.  Because ultimately, any C native code can't do any I/O unless it talks to the OS using one of the OS's provided methods, right??

If my line of thinking is correct on this, does anyone have a book or resource recommendation on where I could find the nuts and bolts of this stuff for Windows, Linux, and Mac?

If my line of thinking is incorrect and its impossible for me to really prevent native code (compiled or uncompiled) from doing I/O operations on its own, please tell me so I don't create an application that I think is secure but really isn't.

In an absolutely ideal world, I don't want to require the plugins to distribute uncompiled code.  I'd like to allow the developers to compile and keep their code to themselves.  Perhaps I could scan the binaries for signatures that pertain to I/O access????

Comment: The only think that do came to my mind is to isolate the plugins in separate processes and sandbox them allowing communication via IPC. The details how to sandbox application would vary but I don't think is's possible to do via DLLs. Other way would be to embed interpreter which prohibits I/O such as LUA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandboxing a program executing code is certainly harder than merely scanning the code for specific accesses! For example, the program could synthesize assembler statements doing system calls.

The original approach on UNIXes is to `chroot()` the program but I think there are problems with that approach, too. Another approach is a secured environment like selinux, possible combined with `chroot()`. The modern approach used to do things like that seems to run the program in a virtual machine: upon start of the program fire up a suitable snapshot of a VM. Upon termination just rewind to tbe snaphot. That merely requires that the allowed accesses are somehow channeled somewhere.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by synthesizing assembler statements doing system calls?

Comment: System calls on UNIXes are just assembler statements, i.e., you can call `write()` without the symbols for this function ever showing up. Assembler code can easily be embedded into C source but even without that you can use deliberate out of bound memory writes to manipulate the stack and make function call things they are not meant to call. Although it will generally not be possible to call code in data segments, putting things on the stack and causing other than intended arguments to be use isn't that hard. ... and you will have something to interact with the world.

Comment: I'm not enough of an hacker to create a demo but I would have little hope that I can detect all ways in the code (whether source or binary) in which an attempt to gain malicious access to resources is made.

Answer (score 1):

Even a VM doesn't block I/O. It can block network traffic very easily though.

If you want to make sure the plugin doesn't do I/O you can scan it's DLL for all it's import functions and run the function list against a blacklist of I/O functions.
Windows has the `dumpbin` util and Linux has `nm`. Both can be run via a `system()` function call and the output of the tools be directed to  files.

Of course, you can write your own analyzer but it's much harder.

User code can't do I/O on it's own. Only the kernel. If youre worried about the plugin gaining ring0/kernel privileges than you need to scan the ASM of the DLL for I/O instructions.

Comment: A VM doesn't block I/O?  I was under the impression that VM is the absolute best way to sandbox an application.  Sure, the application can write to virtualized disks within the VM, but I've never heard of an application being able to get outside that box.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "VM". A Virtual Machine running under a hypervisor is the ultimate sandbox. But a Virtual Machine used to provide a runtime environment (_e.g._, Java's JVM) doesn't help much at all.

Comment: @Jim - Yes, A VM (e.g. VirtualBox) is an excellent method for sandboxing - it will not damage the host OS. But processes inside the VM have I/O. This I/O may only affect virtual devices, but that's till I/O. From your question I understood that you wanted to test IF plugins do I/O or not.

Comment: I see.  Well the reason I was talking about restricting I/O was for the purpose of keeping data secure.  For instance, I'm not so worried about a rogue plugin corrupting data in memory so long as I can guarantee that backups on disk are kept secure.  That way, in the case that memory data is corrupted and the corrupted data gets saved out by the application to disk, you can at least go back to a previous backup to recover good data.  I just need an ecosystem that provides some kind of fail safe data protection.

Comment: Elaborating on that, a Virtual Box provides a fail safe ecosystem, because you can back up the virtual disk snapshot.  If the snapshot becomes compromised, you can always return to a previous snapshot.  And there is no way for the plugin to tamper with snapshot backups.

Comment: That's correct, but your question was how to scan the binaries for I/O.